# Enabling a button after number of edittexts has been filled

Tags: c#, android, android-edittext, xamarin, android-button

I want to make an activity with few edittext fields and a button which should be disabled until the most important of these fields has been filled. This is the code I am using but the button is staying disabled the whole time:

```
 doneButton implementation
        if((isEmpty(inputType)) || (isEmpty(inputAmount)) || (isEmpty(inputSupplier)))
            doneButton.Enabled = false;
        else
            doneButton.Enabled = true;
```

This is the code for the isEmpty() method, which is checking if the edittext is empty or not:

```
private Boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
        return etText.Text.ToString().Length == 0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
inputType.AfterTextChanged += new EventHandler<AfterTextChangedEventArgs> (OnTextChange);
inputAmount.AfterTextChanged += new EventHandler<AfterTextChangedEventArgs> (OnTextChange);
inputSupplier.AfterTextChanged += new EventHandler<AfterTextChangedEventArgs> (OnTextChange);
```

where the OnTextChange() method is this:

```
public void OnTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if((isEmpty(inputType)) || (isEmpty(inputAmount)) || (isEmpty(inputSupplier)))
            doneButton.Enabled = false;
        else
            doneButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the TextChanged event:

```
EditText input = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
input.TextChanged += input_TextChanged;
```

and then define the event handler for it?

```
private void input_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("input text changed");
    // if text bigger than 0, enable the button, otherwise disable it
}
```

Much cleaner IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this implementation(your code to check if the button stays disabled) inside the TextWatcher#afterTextChanged method , which you would add as a TextChanged listener. You will need to do this for all the edit texts you think are important.

Something like this:

```
inputType.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if((isEmpty(inputType)) || (isEmpty(inputAmount)) || (isEmpty(inputSupplier)))
            doneButton.setEnabled(false);
        else
            doneButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

});
```

Similar listeners over `inputAmount` and `inputSupplier` should do the task.

Comment: I was also thinking of using TextWatcher but I don't know how to implement it in Xamarin ..

Answer (score 0):

The question is: On which event did you attach this code?

You can, for example, create a TextWatcher object and attach it to the relevant text fields. Something like:

```
inputType.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

In this watcher you would do the checks you have written and do:

```
doneButton.setEnabled(true/false);
```